# How to get the value from ngrx store

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an angular 8 project and I am using `ngrx` to store an array of objects in a state store. I managed to do that, but now, I want to make a `post request` to the server with the data that is in the state store.

```
this.dataService.postData(this.store.pipe(select('dataStore')));
```

That is the code I am trying and it is not working.
Thank you

Comment: `this.store.value`?

Comment: `this.store.value.StateReducer.dataStore;`

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to perform side effect. To do that you should do the following in your component/service -

```
this.store.pipe(select('dataStore'), 
                take(1)
                switchMap((data) => {
                  return this.dataService.postData(data);
                }
               ).subscribe(responseOfDataService => {
                  //do whatever you want to do with the response
                  console.log(responseOfDataService);
               });
```

BTW - To handle the side effect you should try ngrx Effects - https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

Comment: You are right, I will now look into it, thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Simplest Answer

```
this.store.pipe(select('dataStore'), take(1)).subscribe((data) => {

this.dataService.postData(data).subscribe();

});
```

Comment: Hi, just want to know if `this.store.pipe(select('dataStore'), take(1)).subscribe((data)` is a sync call, so that once this line is executed, data becomes available and the line in {} got executed. thanks

Comment: No, it's not a sync call

Comment: It should be. If it's async when will it return? when dataStore is changed? it could never be changed so `postData` never get called?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
import { createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

const dataSelector = createFeatureSelector('dataStore');

this.store.select(dataSelector).subscribe(
   (data) => {
     this.dataService.postData(data)
   }
);
```

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. It is sending a `Subscriber` object.